# Compilation error when trying to use vector<ostringstream>

Tags: c++, vector, stringstream

I try to compile this code, but I get an error:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::ostringstream> v;
    v.reserve(100);
    return 0;
}
```

The error message says something about being unable to default construct an `ostringstream`. I can really make no sense of the error message while compiling with either gcc or clang. Why does `reserve()` try to construct anything? Here is the code: http://ideone.com/lXQRkH

Comment: I see. The reserve can possibly reallocate, which tries to copy because move is not implemented by gcc.

Comment: @chris Your and OP's comments together make a nice answer.

Comment: @Angew, I guess they do. My comment didn't start out so long, but then I went to town editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `reserve`, the vector needs to end up with enough space for 100 elements. This means `reserve` must have the possibility of copying or moving everything.

Streams are non-copyable. For this reason, they cannot be stored in standard containers before C++11. In C++11, the streams can be moved, making them work fine in standard containers. The missing piece here is that libstdc++ currently has not implemented movable streams. This [does compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e607a57e2938460) with libc++.

Expect to see this working in [GCC 5.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html).